# How can I copy/upsize a table from access 2013 to sql server using vba

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, connection-string

I am currently working on a project where is need to send existing tables with all their fields to an sql database (backend).

what i have so far is to generate an make-table query and then execute it, but i allways get the error....

> "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is
>   misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

the generated string is `SELECT * INTO (Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=stserver;DATABASE=stdatabase;UID=userid;PWD=userpass).AAAANewTable FROM AAAANewTable WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;`

of cause the stdatabase and userid ect, are string variables :-)

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax? or give an example of what the correct syntax should look like?

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: There is an official tool for this: [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v7.8 for Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255).

Comment: Hi, Sorry,maybe i wasnt clear...my fault :-) the tables that have to be sent to the sql database are from a collection that is created on the fly and are passed through various other functions, after those functions are finnished, then and only then can the table be sent to the sql server. sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: I see. But you could use the tool to study the SQL created. Then save the SQL as a "master" and modify it with simple string manipulation when you wish to export the on-fly tables.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I will give it a go and see if i can intergrate it into my app. thank you for your help anyway :-)

Comment: Hi again, I have been looking at the created script from the migration assistant, but i think this aproach will be far to complex for what is needed. From what i have seen so far, it should be possible in a function in access in a simple way.... "If its to complicated then it's ("usually") wrong!" :-)

Comment: You may be able to reduce the created SQL a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using square brackets around your SQL Server connection string - that's the format expected by MS-Access `[Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=stserver;DATABASE=stdatabase;UID=userid;PWD=userpass]` - and I'm assuming your SQL actually is showing the true variable names - you're not really using variables in it the string?

Comment: @dbmitch, Yes i have tried that, and yes the actual string(value) gets passed in the passed in the string i.e... stserver = "Bob@1234!5" for example!

Comment: @Gustav, I will be going with the create table query, I have created the correct create table string already and tested the standard format that sql uses, this works fine, how ever my next problem is that i need to do this on the fly, meaning .... for each field in rst.fields CreateTblStr = CreateTblSTr & rst!field1 varchar(255), etc.... any ides/ examples would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: You should open a new question. Few will see this comment, and I'm on my home for weekend.

Comment: You should also edit your question with the format that is now working.

Comment: Yea dbmitch, I will do that, i have wrote a new module that set all the necessary items into a nice create table statement, works great, just a bit more debugging and it's finished :-) this post can be closed " How ever I don't think I have the rights to do that!" Thank you all for your feed back, and great thnx for @Gustav for his quick intervention :-) If needs be, I will post my module? because I think it could be very valuable for people having this same problem.